# Android search input in modal listView

Tags: android, android-listview, modal-dialog

I would like to ask how to create in the right way searchable listView displayed in the modal window ? (See screenshot from iOS below).

[image]

Is any customized library for this? Or i should to use searching input using in the actionBar or custom modal view?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out: 
[Android Adding Search Functionality to ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Comment: i think that this is not useful for me, because i need display list in the modal windows.